# Winrt C# - Sort Gridview and group alphabetically

Tags: c#, gridview, listbox, group-by, windows-runtime

I come to you today because I don't know how to resolve this question. I want to order my Gridview alphabetically, which is easy. But I want to add a vignet of the letter before each group of the first letter. A comportement like the "Contact" application of Windows 8.

Like this :

```
 - A :
 aaaa
 aaaann
 aananana
- B :
bbbaaaa
bbbabbbb
bbbaccc
 -C : 
cccc...
```

This is the code of the gridview. I bind a data to this gridview and I want to add between each group of letter another vignet with the letter of the group.

```
<Grid>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data}" 
                                  IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionMode="None">
                            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" ItemWidth="280" />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                        </GridView>
                    </DataTemplate>
        </Grid>
```

If you have an idea ? Thanks for your time,

Regards.

Comment: No effort shown to find the answer, while that is one of the common problems with tons of samples and answers online.

Comment: @FilipSkakun FYI (to save you time in the future), there's a close reason for that already. "Off-topic" -> "*Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.*"

Comment: Right, somehow I looked for it and didn't see it. Too much text. Bad UX. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bingoogle and you'll find an answer. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/GroupedGridView-77c59e8e

The `SampleDataSource` in the sample app has this method:

```
    internal List<GroupInfoList<object>> GetGroupsByLetter() 
    { 
        List<GroupInfoList<object>> groups = new List<GroupInfoList<object>>(); 

        var query = from item in Collection 
                    orderby ((Item)item).Title 
                    group item by ((Item)item).Title[0] into g 
                    select new { GroupName = g.Key, Items = g }; 
        foreach (var g in query) 
        { 
            GroupInfoList<object> info = new GroupInfoList<object>(); 
            info.Key = g.GroupName; 
            foreach (var item in g.Items) 
            { 
                info.Add(item); 
            } 
            groups.Add(info); 
        } 

        return groups; 

    } 
}
```

If you look at Scenario2.xaml.cs - it calls that method and assigns the result to a `CollectionViewSource`:

```
List<GroupInfoList<object>> dataLetter = _storeData.GetGroupsByLetter(); 

// sets the CollectionViewSource in the XAML page resources to the data groups 
cvs2.Source = dataLetter;
```

`cvs2` is defined as a resource in the XAML code for the page:

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage.Resources> 
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="cvs2" IsSourceGrouped="true" /> 
</common:LayoutAwarePage.Resources>
```

The `GridView` then uses the `CollectionViewSource` as its `ItemsCollection` as well as defines the `DataTemplates` for the groups and the items:

```
        <GridView x:Name="ItemsByLetter"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  
                  Height="325" 
                  Width="1150" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs2}}" 
                  ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="False" 
                  ContainerContentChanging="ItemsByLetter_ContainerContentChanging" 
                  BorderBrush="{StaticResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="1"> 

            <GridView.ItemsPanel> 
                <ItemsPanelTemplate> 
                    <ItemsWrapGrid GroupHeaderPlacement="Left" /> 
                </ItemsPanelTemplate> 
            </GridView.ItemsPanel> 
            <GridView.ItemTemplate> 
                <DataTemplate> 
                    <local:ItemViewer/> 
                </DataTemplate> 
            </GridView.ItemTemplate> 

            <GridView.GroupStyle> 
                <GroupStyle> 
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate> 
                        <DataTemplate> 
                            <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="10"> 
                                <TextBlock Text='{Binding Key}' Foreground="{StaticResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}" FontSize="25" Margin="5" /> 
                            </Grid> 
                        </DataTemplate> 
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate> 
                </GroupStyle> 
            </GridView.GroupStyle> 
        </GridView>
```

Comment: Right, I just rushed to help and didn't have the time to add more details. I'm sure there are also discussions on Meta about rushing to downvote answers as I am sure there are also discussions about closing questions without trying to help the asker amend their ways. Mea culpa.

Comment: Your answer had been here for at least 30 minutes when I downvoted it.  I don't feel like that's rushing to downvote.  I don't understand your other comment about "helping the asker amend their ways."  Regardless, I wasn't trying to antagonize you, or anything like that (I was just explaining myself).  I apologize if it came across that way.  I've removed my downvote, because I think this answer is useful, post-edit.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that and sorry, just a bad morning after 5 hours of sleep does that to you. Even after having fun coding XAML stuff till 1:30am. :)